# If not clicked for 30s, apply CSS once, remove it, and re-iterate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have this funky little [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdwKLB) with an animation which I wish to run only if the user hasn't clicked on the `<div class="someDiv">` for 30 seconds.

What I'm asking is, can anyone point me in the right direction, so when someone *doesn't* click on:

```
<div class="someDiv">
</div>
```

..for 30 seconds, this CSS will apply (ONCE) via appending id, similar to `$(".someDiv").attr("id", "#theBounce");` and removing it in a reverse manner.

```
#theBounce {
  background-color:red;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:5%;

  -moz-animation: bounce 1.5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1.5s infinite;
  animation: bounce 1.5s infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
```

Meaning that a click will force the scripts counter to start over, and a lack of clicking for 30s will apply the CSS for at least 1,5s, and then remove it, and then start the timer. It might be my Googling skills at fault here, but I just can't figure out how to make this work. **It's the timing/reset on click part I haven't figured out really.**

A link, an idea, a suggestion. I'll be happy for all of it. Thanks.

Comment: `setTimeout()` the animation trigger function; `clearTimeout()` it and then set it again on click.

Comment: @DanielBeck I'm gonna be experimenting for a while, hence the lack of response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use setTimeout.

On document load start your setTimeout by defining a variable equal to the timer which after a certain number of milliseconds adds your content.  Then redefine your timer variable to a new setTimeout for a new amount of milliseconds.

```
var myTimer;
myTimer = setTimeout(function(){ /*do stuff after 3 seconds*/ }, 3000);
```

Then if someone does something to stop the timer you can stop the timer by:

```
clearTimeout(myTimer);
```

Here's an example:

```js
(function () {
  var myTimer,
      announce = document.getElementById("announcement"),
      button = document.getElementById("stopIt");
  function firstTimer () {
      announcement.innerHTML = '';
      myTimer = setTimeout(function () {
          populateContent();
      }, 500);
  }
  function populateContent () {
      announcement.innerHTML = 'push the button!!';
      myTimer = setTimeout(function () {
          firstTimer();
      }, 500);
  }
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
  });
  firstTimer();
}());
```

```css
#announcement {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 5ex;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="announcement"></div>
<button type="button" id="stopIt">Stop!!</button>
```

Comment: Experimenting, hence the lack of response. Thank you.

Comment: I just posted an example.

Comment: better to mention him/her in your comment .. to alert him/her that you sent a new thing :)

Comment: @AlgernopK. I just posted an example for you.

Comment: Called in to nightshift and then they said "there's no need, we solved it". I'll be checking things out in 1 hr or so

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, so someone may have a better answer, but you can use the setTimeout function in Javascript to do this, I think.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

The first example on that page seems similar to what you'd want, here's an untested suggestion:

HTML:

Live Example

Set CSS bounce after 30 seconds

Reset timer

Javascript:
    var timeoutID;

```
function setBounce() {
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(bounceIt, 30000);
}

function bounceIt() {
  // Code to find the bounce div, apply the CSS style to it,
  // and then add a new timeout on the CSS to remove the style after 1.5s

}

function unbounceIt(bounceTimeoutID) {
  window.clearTimeout(bounceTimeoutID);
}

function resetBounceTimer() {
  window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}
```

Hopefully this is a step in the right direction

Comment: Experimenting, hence the lack of response. Thank you.